# One SQL statement to take the place of two

Tags: mysql

I am trying to shorten my code and I'm stuck. Currently I perform two separate queries to get the data I need from two separate tables. The premise is to generate a report comparing two different classes test score based on gender and ethnicity.

Query 1:

```
SELECT g.ethnicity AS dataPointA, 
count(case when t.fall_spring = 1 then t.studentID end) as countA,
round(avg(case when t.fall_spring = 1 then t.compScore end),0) as scoreA,
round(avg(case when t.fall_spring = 1 then t.compNP end),1) as scoreNPA

from table1 t
JOIN aall_students s
ON t.studentID=s.studentID 
JOIN aall_ethnicities g
ON s.ethnicityID=g.ethnicityID
WHERE t.classof = 2021 and s.gender = 'F'
group by s.ethnicityID

Results query 1:

dataPointA        countA   scoreA    scoreNPA
--------------------------------------------
African American |   18   | 914   |   56.6  |
--------------------------------------------
Asian            |    8   | 998   |   71.4  |
--------------------------------------------
Hispanic/Latino  |    5   | 936   |   63.0  |
--------------------------------------------
Two or More      |   11   | 1005  |   72.3  |
--------------------------------------------
White            |   28   | 1028  |   76.7  |
```

Query 2:
Note that the WHERE clause in the 2nd query is different and that the number of rows returned is also different.

```
SELECT g.ethnicity AS dataPointB, 
count(case when t.fall_spring = 1 then t.studentID end) as countB,
round(avg(case when t.fall_spring = 1 then t.compScore end),0) as scoreB,
round(avg(case when t.fall_spring = 1 then t.compNP end),1) as scoreNPB

from table2 t
JOIN aall_students s
ON t.studentID=s.studentID 
JOIN aall_ethnicities g
ON s.ethnicityID=g.ethnicityID
WHERE t.classof = 2022 and s.gender = 'F'
group by s.ethnicityID

Results query 2:

dataPointB        countB   scoreB    scoreNPB
----------------------------------------------
African American |   12   | 838    |   40.0   |
----------------------------------------------
Asian            |    7   | 957    |   65.9   |
----------------------------------------------
Hispanic/Latino  |    7   | 931    |   59.6   |
----------------------------------------------
Native American  |    1   | 940    |   64.0   |
----------------------------------------------
Two or More      |   18   | 963    |   66.1   |
----------------------------------------------
White            |   32   | 1074   |   84.1   |
```

Notice that the queries return a different number of rows, meaning there were no Native Americans in the first query and one in the 2nd.

It would be less querying and less processing if I could join the two queries into one so , for example, all data for African Americans from both queries fell on one row. It would also eliminate processing on the script side and potential for errors.

I tried UNION, JOIN in all it's various forms, and extensive Googling, and could not come up with any kind of a solution. Any suggestions to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

The desired result would look like this:

```
dataPointA        countA   scoreA    scoreNPA   dataPointB       countB   scoreB   scoreNPB
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
African American |   18   | 914   |   56.6  |  African American |   12   | 838   |   40.0  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Asian            |    8   | 998   |   71.4  |  Asian            |    7   | 957   |   65.9  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hispanic/Latino  |    5   | 936   |   63.0  |  Hispanic/Latino  |    7   | 931   |   59.6  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
null             |  null  | null  |   null  |  Native American  |    1   | 940   |   64.0  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Two or More      |   11   | 1005  |   72.3  |  Two or More      |   18   | 963   |   66.1  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
White            |   28   | 1028  |   76.7  |  White            |   32   | 1074  |   84.1  |
```

With UNION ALL I get a workable array, which requires some manipulate on the code side. I also added the "class" column suggested in a reply to differentiate the tables:

```
dataPoint           class     count    score      scoreNP   
------------------------------------------------------------
African American |  2021   |   18    |  914    |   56.6    |
------------------------------------------------------------
Asian            |  2021   |    8    |  998    |   71.4    |
------------------------------------------------------------
Hispanic/Latino  |  2021   |    5    |  936    |   63.0    |
------------------------------------------------------------
Two or More      |  2021   |   11    | 1005    |   72.3    |
------------------------------------------------------------
White            |  2021   |   28    | 1028    |   76.7    |
------------------------------------------------------------
African American |  2022   |   12    |  838    |   40.0    |
------------------------------------------------------------
Asian            |  2022   |    7    |  957    |   65.9    |
------------------------------------------------------------
Hispanic/Latino  |  2022   |    7    |  931    |   59.6    |
------------------------------------------------------------
Native American  |  2022   |    1    |  940    |   64.0    |
------------------------------------------------------------
Two or More      |  2022   |   18    |  963    |   66.1    |
------------------------------------------------------------
White            |  2022   |   32    | 1074    |   84.1    |
```

Comment: What would the desired result look like? Also, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) (but well done for presenting two valid queries - a wondrously rare thing on SO)

Comment: Is `count(case when t.fall_spring = 1 then t.studentID end)` the same as `SUM(t.fall_spring = 1)`,

Comment: Strawberry, yes, count is the same as the SUM, a bit of sloppy cut and paste coding on my part. Thanks for pointing it out. Also, I added the "desired" results above in the post.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a job for UNION ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html).  Why ALL? a plain UNION tries to deduplicate the rows, and you don't need that.

Try doing this:

```
     SELECT 'A' datatype, whatever, whatever
       FROM table1 ... WHERE whatever
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'B' datatype, whatever, whatever
       FROM table2 ... WHERE whatever
```

You'll get a single result set with an extra column called `datatype` (in my example). You can use that column to tell apart results from the two different tables.